# RxAndroid: How to add additional methods in Observer and Observable

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android

Observer has onNext(), OnError() and onComplete().
Is there a way to add an additional method?

There is a possibility that the object received via the stream is of two types instead of the same type. And both possibilities are a success scenario. They are just handled differently by the observer.

Now, with callbacks, one would add a new method to handle this. 
But not sure how this would be done with Rx. 
Or is there another way of handling this without having to add a new method?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by adding methods? You implement the interface and define additional methods you can call.

Comment: The observable uses an emitter to send calls to onNext(), onError() and onCompleted(). Even if i implement the Observer and add a new method, how will Rx know to allow me access to that method via the emitter in the Observable?

Comment: Why can you not switch on the type of the result (or use the visitor pattern if there is a prohibition against this) in the `onNext()`? This would probably better suit the principal of least surprise

Comment: could you please explain with an example

Comment: Indeed, how would a precompiled, interface driven library know about your method and its semantics?

Comment: so any way around it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this is by using a common super class which can hold both objects.

In Kotlin you can do this with `sealed class` in Java do it with a simple POJO. One downside is that you have to use `instanceOf` and `casting` to use the actual type.

```
public class Result<T> {
    public T result;

    public Result(T result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}

public class Result1 extends Result<Object1> {

    public Result1(Object1 result) {
        super(result);
    }
}

public class Result2 extends Result<Object2> {

    public Result2(Object2 result) {
        super(result);
    }
}
```

Your `Observable` can emit `Result` objects, and you can cast to either result based on what you got on the `onNext` method.

Comment: thanks. but do you know of a way to have additional methods ?